# Using android-extensions`s Parcelize annotation on objects that extends Parceable sealed classes

Tags: kotlin, annotations, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using kotlin android extensions to auto generate my Parcelables, but given the following code I'm getting `'Parcelable' should be a class`.

the code:

```
sealed class Action : Parcelable

@Parcelize
object Run : Action()

@Parcelize
data class Ask(
    val question: String
) : Action()
```

My understanding is that it is impossible to use `@Parcelize` in an `object` (Once it is working on the Ask class) in the way I'm doing it.

I want to use the `Parcelable` annotation in an object that extends a `sealed class`, so I'm do not know how to do it and do not write the following boilerplate.

```
object Run : Action() {

    override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int) {}
    override fun describeContents() = 0

    @JvmField
    val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<Run> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) = Run
        override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<Run?>(size)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you add `@Parcelize` on the sealed class?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, we can't use it on sealed or abstract classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have you Kotlin up to date.

You can follow an [example here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22576).

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using the version `1.2.51` but the issue was solved on the version `1.2.60`.